# Saving binary content of pdf file to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, pdf, url, binary-data

Is it possible to save binary content of pdf into javascript variable?
I have a webpage with url to saving pdf file and I need to save pdf file into javascript variable. I guess it should be binary data.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". In the future, please try and do the task yourself before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XHR with response type `blob`:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.pdf", true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = oReq.response;
  // `blob` contains the PDF content
};

oReq.send();
```

Source: [Sending and Receiving Binary Data, MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)